# Underline the first character of a MenuItem?

Tags: java, character, menuitem, underline

Please help me with this matter. Is there any way to underline the first character 
of this MenuItem in Java? This is a WindowApplication writing by Eclipse.

[image]

Comment: which software is that?  please edit your post and update the tag... it looks like it may be excel but it's not clear.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me :D

Comment: it would also be helpful to include any code you are using in the post

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is an eclipse RCP application, or at least a GUI based on SWT (as opposed to swing or JavaFX).

**Mnemonics** is the term.

```
menuitem.setText("Zoom &In");
```

to underline "I."

Besides you probably want **accelerator**: Ctrl +/-/0 are customary for zoom in/out/reset.

```
menuitem.setAccelerator(SWT.CONTROL|'+');
```

Sometimes the underlining is only visible in some mode.

Comment: I tried using menuitem.setText("Zoom &In"). But it only takes effect when i right-click then press I. Is there any way to Zoom In just by Pressing I or  CTRL+I? Thanks :D

Comment: At a point in history they had the idea only to underline when in some GUI mode. I think this is a system setting. (I work in Linux.) You could try `menuitem.setAccelerator(SWT.CONTROL|'I');` or better Alt I, as Ctrl I (ASCII 9) is the tab character.